# Programmatically logging in to a website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httprequest

How does one log in to a website programmatically?

I just want to check that the provided username and password of a website is correct or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Edited to clean up the tone a bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do this from .NET is [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).  You would do something like:

```
 using (var browser = new IE("http://mysite.com"))
 {
  browser.TextField(Find.ByName("email")).TypeText("my@email.com");
  browser.TextField(Find.ByName("password")).TypeText("password");
  browser.Button(Find.ByName("login")).Click();

  if (browser.ContainsText("Welcome my@email.com!"))
  {
    // Success
  } 
 }
```

To do it with HttpWebRequest, you would:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = postContent.Length;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(postContent);
}

using (var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
  _status = res.StatusCode;
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
  {
    response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Just to add a 3rd way, you could also use WebClient:

```
var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("email", "my@email.com");
nvc.Add("password", "password");

var wc = new WebClient();
byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadValues("http://mysite.com",nvc);
string responseText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray));
```

Comment: Execute that code too many times with the wrong credentials and pretty surely the user will be locked out of his account.

Comment: but how could i know that user logged in successfully in the code.... ?

could it be done through through HTTP Request ? (i think it is good for the beginner like me)

Thnks in anticipation !!!

Comment: With Watin, you would then check browser.ContainsText("Welcome my@email.com!") or something along those lines.  You absolutely could do it with HttpWebRequest, but the code is much more difficult.  I'll edit my answer and add the code above.

Comment: I won't do it for you - I don't want to be accused of hacking into their site.  But I can tell you that all 3 work fine.  I'd delete the comment with your login info if I were you.

Comment: thanks for your great help !!!

i have deleted my last request as suggested by you ... basically i just want to get out of this situation :( i have already wasted too much time on this but all in vain .... Anyway thanks once again consultutah